# find and replace in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am looking for an efficient method to find and replace in android studio. where I can find a string using regex and replace the selected string with its substring.

e.g.

- constants.LOG_FILE_PATH -> SETTINGS['LOG_FILE_PATH']
- constants.LOG_DIR -> SETTINGS['LOG_DIR']

I have following regex for find

constants.[A-Z_]*

which selects **constants.LOG_FILE_PATH** and **constants.LOG_DIR**

but how to modify the replace string so that the above strings can be replaced by SETTINGS['**LOG_FILE_PATH**'] and SETTINGS['**LOG_DIR**'] respectively. I have to find and replace many strings in my project so manual find and replace is little overhead.

Edit 1: If you know how to do in pycharm or intellij-idea it will work in android studio also, thats why i have added tags pycharm and intellij-idea

Comment: In android studio you can find and replace using cntrl+shift +R

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at `Structural Replace`. Use the `Find Actions` shortcut (`CMD + Shift + A`) and type structural and the option should appear.

I guess something like the following may work:

**Search template**

```
constants.$log$
```

**Replacement template**

```
SETTINGS["$log$"]
```

Disclaimer, this is untested.